# XML deserialization in C# is returning null array even when XML has data

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, soap

I'm trying to deserialize an XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:catalogProductListResponse>
         <storeView SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:catalogProductEntity[609]" xsi:type="ns1:catalogProductEntityArray">
            <item xsi:type="ns1:catalogProductEntity">
               <product_id xsi:type="xsd:string">36</product_id>
               <sku xsi:type="xsd:string">000975</sku>
               <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Beauty Dermo HTM - Vacuoterapia</name>
               <set xsi:type="xsd:string">4</set>
               <type xsi:type="xsd:string">simple</type>
               <category_ids SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[9]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfString">
                  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">4</item>
               </category_ids>
               <website_ids SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfString">
                  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">1</item>
               </website_ids>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="ns1:catalogProductEntity">
               <product_id xsi:type="xsd:string">37</product_id>
               <sku xsi:type="xsd:string">004279</sku>
               <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Effect HTM - Radiofrequência</name>
               <set xsi:type="xsd:string">4</set>
               <type xsi:type="xsd:string">simple</type>
               <category_ids SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[8]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfString">
                  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">4</item>
               </category_ids>
               <website_ids SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfString">
                  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">1</item>
               </website_ids>
            </item>
            ...[OTHER MANY ITENS]
         </storeView>
      </ns1:catalogProductListResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In this class

```
public class ProductListResponse
{
    // NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Envelope
    {
        private EnvelopeBody bodyField;

        private string encodingStyleField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public EnvelopeBody Body
        {
            get
            {
                return this.bodyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.bodyField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
        public string encodingStyle
        {
            get
            {
                return this.encodingStyleField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.encodingStyleField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public partial class EnvelopeBody
    {
        private catalogProductListResponse catalogProductListResponseField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "urn:Magento")]
        public catalogProductListResponse catalogProductListResponse
        {
            get
            {
                return this.catalogProductListResponseField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.catalogProductListResponseField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "urn:Magento")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "urn:Magento", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class catalogProductListResponse
    {
        private storeView storeViewField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("storeView")]
        public storeView storeView
        {
            get
            {
                return this.storeViewField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.storeViewField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName = "catalogProductEntityArray")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class storeView
    {
        private storeViewItem[] itemField;

        private string arrayTypeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("item")]
        public storeViewItem[] item
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/")]
        public string arrayType
        {
            get
            {
                return this.arrayTypeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.arrayTypeField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName = "catalogProductEntity")]
    public partial class storeViewItem
    {

        private ushort product_idField;

        private string skuField;

        private string nameField;

        private byte setField;

        private string typeField;

        private storeViewItemCategory_ids category_idsField;

        private storeViewItemWebsite_ids website_idsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public ushort product_id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.product_idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.product_idField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
        public string sku
        {
            get
            {
                return this.skuField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.skuField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public byte set
        {
            get
            {
                return this.setField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.setField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string type
        {
            get
            {
                return this.typeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.typeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public storeViewItemCategory_ids category_ids
        {
            get
            {
                return this.category_idsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.category_idsField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public storeViewItemWebsite_ids website_ids
        {
            get
            {
                return this.website_idsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.website_idsField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class storeViewItemCategory_ids
    {

        private byte[] itemField;

        private string arrayTypeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("item")]
        public byte[] item
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/")]
        public string arrayType
        {
            get
            {
                return this.arrayTypeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.arrayTypeField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class storeViewItemWebsite_ids
    {

        private byte itemField;

        private string arrayTypeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public byte item
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/")]
        public string arrayType
        {
            get
            {
                return this.arrayTypeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.arrayTypeField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the code

```
var deserializedDocument = SerializacaoHelper.Deserialize<ProductListResponse.Envelope>(xmlDocument);

public static T Deserialize<T>(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream();
        xmlDoc.Save(xmlStream);
        xmlStream.Position = 0;
        T obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);

        xmlStream.Flush();

        return obj;
    }
```

The class was generated with the Visual Studio automatic generator. To simulate it is due, with the XML in the clipboard, to follow the steps *Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML as Classes*.

The function that deserializes is being executed, however, the **storeView** attribute is null, even having child nodes inside it in the XML.

Where is the error? In class? In the deserialization code? I can not understand why the StoreView attribute is null if in XML it has data.

Comment: Something went wrong around `public byte[] item`, that should have been string[]. I can't spot a cause  so fast, review your attributes.

Comment: I actually didn't even know of the functionality to generate classes from an XML string. That said, it looks like the type inferrence is not the best here. I would suggest to get an XML Schema document and use the XSD.exe tool to generate the classes from the schema instead of the XML instance.

Comment: Yes, "review your attributes" is nonsense.  I don't think the Copy/Past generator even looks at those. A good XSD is needed, worst case you have to write one.